# Normalize nested dict in Cerberus

Tags: python, cerberus

I'd like to have default values in nested dicts with Cerberus normalize function. Unfortunately it's not working.
I have code such as:

```py
from yaml import load, Loader
from cerberus import Validator

text_schema = """
server:
  type: dict
  required: True
  schema:
    host:
      required: True
      type: string
    api:
      type: dict
      required: True
      schema:
        enabled:
          type: boolean
          required: True
          default: True
"""

testyaml = """
server:
  host: hostname
"""
schema = load(text_schema, Loader=Loader)
doc = load(testyaml, Loader=Loader)
v = Validator(schema, purge_unknown=True)
print(v.normalized(doc))
```

I end up with:

```json
{'server': {'host': 'hostname'}}
```

and I'd expect to have:

```json
{'server': {'host': 'hostname', 'api': {'enabled': true}}}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if this is proper, but simply adding an empty default value to the `api` key works.

```
text_schema = """
server:
  type: dict
  required: True
  schema:
    host:
      required: True
      type: string
    api:
      type: dict
      required: True
      default: {}
      schema:
        enabled:
          type: boolean
          required: True
          default: True
"""
```

Using the above schema, I get:
`{'server': {'host': 'hostname', 'api': {'enabled': True}}}`